# How to install a driver for HP LaserJet P1102 printer?

Tags: 10.04, printing, hp

Good Morning,

I have a HP LaserJet P1102 printer, that I could not install on Ubuntu 10.04 despite all my efforts.

What can I do?

MfG

---

> Guten Morgen,
>
> ich habe einen Drucker von HP Laserjet p1102 den ich bein besten
>   Willen an Ubuntu vers 10.04 nichtzum Laufen bekomme.
>
> Was kann ich t?
>
> MfG

Comment: How to you connect the printer to your PC? Wifi? USB? If USB connected open a Terminal (Strg+Alt+T) and type: lsusb Post the output here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a topic on [Answers Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/194406) regarding your printer:

> Smart Installer is enabled in your device. If this is enabled, your device will be detected as CDRom from where you can install the software on windows.

The solution there involves downloading and running the Windows-driver on a Windows computer to disable this "feature" using **SIUtility.exe**.

If that is not an option you may have a look at [this (closed) question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94637/hp-laserjet-p1102) where the OP said they succeeded with **hp-setup** after they deleted all printers,

Alternatively, in case your printer is not recognized as a printer but as CD-ROM drive, you could try to change or define a new [Udev rule](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) for the printer. This method is suitable for advanced users only and it is may not work (we could not test this here). See also [Debian bug #630648](http://lists.debian.org/debian-printing/2011/06/msg00101.html) on further details.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be explicit support for hp laserjet 1102 printers. Usb or network really doesnt matter much. You can try installing the printer as a generic post-script printer.
or
try isntalling the printer as a simlar model numberd printer. By example:
try using the driver for an HP laserjet 1100 which does have support in lucid.

you can also try the HPLIP drivers available here:
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/gethplip.html